# Help with cURL in Python

Tags: php, python, post, curl, libcurl

I have to POST a request to a server. In the API documentation of the website there is this example that uses cURL in PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.website.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "request=$wrapper");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
;
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But my app is done using Python, so I tried to write something like that but this code doesn't work:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, formatted)  
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)  
html = response.read()  
print html+"\n\n"
```

Can you help me write a working conversion of a PHP cURL program to Python?

Thank you!!

Comment: Did you try that with a simple 'http://www.google.com'? That really should be working...what is the problem that you're seeing?

Comment: SO cut off the http from the url

Comment: @Ldn If you want a good answer, please include a description of the way that the program you're writing fails. It's hard to diagnose your problem with no error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite embarrassing but... the only problem with my code that uses urllib and urllib2 is... that this code do a GET and not a POST !!!

Here my scan using Wireshark:

1- using urllib and urllib2

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Message: GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: GET
        Request URI: /
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    Accept-Encoding: identity\r\n
    Host: api.apptrackr.org\r\n
    Connection: close\r\n
    User-Agent: Python-urllib/2.6\r\n
    \r\n
```

2- using PyCurl

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Message: POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: POST
        Request URI: /
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: PycURL/7.19.5\r\n
    Host: api.website.com\r\n
    Accept: */*\r\n
    Content-Length: 365\r\n
        [Content length: 365]
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
    \r\n
Line-based text data: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    [truncated]         request=%7B%22enc_key%22%3A%22o37vOsNetKgprRE0VsBYefYViP4%2ByB3pjxfkfCYtpgiQ%2ByxONgkhhsxtqAwaXwCrrgx%2BPDuDtMRZNI1ez//4Zw%3D%3D%22%2C%22format%22%3A%22RSA_RC4_Sealed%22%2C%22profile%22%3A%22Ldn%22%2C%22request%22%3A%22bQ%2BHm/
```

so the code works, but it's not right for me because i need a POST, but i will prefer to use NOT PyCurl.
Any idea?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Try adding `data = ""` to the urlopen to change it from a `GET` to a `POST` with no data.

Answer (score 2):

curl is for Python too: http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/

The example could be translated into Python and pycurl like this:

```
import pycurl
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, "http://api.website.com")
c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, "request=%s" % wrapper)
import StringIO
b = StringIO.StringIO()
c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
c.perform()
c.close()
data = b.getvalue()
```

Your Python code using urllib2 looks OK, it should be working. Probably there is an error in something other you did not mention in question; could you be please more specific?

Comment: Native? Are you asking if it is in standard Python library? No, it is not.

Comment: i tried to install pycurl but i get this error, typical of macs:

i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: /usr/lib/libcurl.a: No such file or directory
powerpc-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: /usr/lib/libcurl.a: No such file or directoryi686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: /usr/lib/libcurl.a: No such file or directorylipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccf74ZBD.out

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a packet sniffer to figure out if cURL is sending User-Agent information. If it is, and the service is expecting that information, then use the add_header() method on your [Request](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) (from urllib2 documentation, bottom of page):

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://api.website.com/')
# Your parameter encoding here
req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
# Process the response
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking your code, this should actually work.

```
 import urllib 
 import urllib2

 url = 'http://api.website.com/' 
 values = {'some_key':'some_value'} 
 data = urllib.urlencode(values) 
 req = urllib2.Request(url, data) 
 response = urllib2.urlopen(req) 
 page = response.read()
 print page + '\n\n'
```

What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i get -BAD_REQUEST (400), which means that the request was badly formatted or improperly submitted.

but i'm sure that the request is right formatted! so the problem is in the post

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your data is correct, encoded etc? Are there special requirements for your API?

Without the specific information it is very difficult to help you determine your problem.