# what is the use of pycurl.INFOTYPE_HEADER_OUT?

Tags: python, pycurl

In php there are lines of code like:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

I don't get the exact meaning of it; I assume it is something when set to true means you get the header information along with the response. But it is called against the set methods.

In python's pycurl library the closest I could get to was `pycurl.INFOTYPE_HEADER_OUT`. But it throws error when I call it against set methods:

```
>>> c = pycurl.Curl()
>>> c.setopt(pycurl.INFOTYPE_HEADER_OUT, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pycurl.error: (48, '')
>>> c.getinfo(pycurl.INFOTYPE_HEADER_OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid argument to getinfo
```

What is the correct python statement I have to type in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a setting, but rather a flag that is used for debugging purposes to print the raw headers that are sent *out* by the library.  To use it you need to define a callback as your `DEBUGFUNCTION` and then process the return type:

```
sent_headers = []
received_headers = []
def collect_headers(debug_type, debug_msg):
    if debug_type == pycurl.INFOTYPE_HEADER_OUT:
            sent_headers.append(debug_msg)
    if debug_type == pycurl.INFOTYPE_HEADER_IN:
            received_headers.append(debug_msg)

# somewhere later in the code

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://www.google.com/')
c.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, collect_headers)
c.perform()
```

Here is the relevant bits from the [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html):

> CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION
>
> Pass a pointer to a function that matches the following prototype: int
>   curl_debug_callback (CURL *, curl_infotype, char *, size_t, void *);
>   CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION replaces the standard debug function used when
>   CURLOPT_VERBOSE is in effect. This callback receives debug
>   information, as specified with the curl_infotype argument. This
>   function must return 0. The data pointed to by the char * passed to
>   this function WILL NOT be zero terminated, but will be exactly of the
>   size as told by the size_t argument.
>
> Available curl_infotype values:
>
> CURLINFO_TEXT
>
> The data is informational text.
>
> CURLINFO_HEADER_IN
>
> The data is header (or header-like) data received from the peer.
>
> CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT
>
> The data is header (or header-like) data sent to the peer.
>
> CURLINFO_DATA_IN
>
> The data is protocol data received from the peer.
>
> CURLINFO_DATA_OUT
>
> The data is protocol data sent to the peer.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that pycurl has a particular way to be called if you don't want the response of `perform()` outputted on your screen. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/2776815/145682

I mean that is simply how to use pycurl. Its not exactly similar to php's curl interface...